# How to model stats in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm getting started with my first neo4j project. I want to create an app that can give you stats about a soccer game. I came up with this model and I wanted do read what you think about it.

[image]

The way I see it, doing it this way - where every stat is a node - I could easily answer questions like who made more assists. Or what are the aggregate stats for each team.

My questions are regarding scale. How does this scale? Teams and players eventually will have a lot of relations of the type stat_of.

Answer (score 2):

As it is, you are likely to get into trouble as stats increase and more games are played, in that you're going to be searching for stats based on multiple dimensions, and it may require some non-trivial filtering to finally get all of the dimensions you want.

For example, there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42372580/92359) with a similar model and the requirement: find the top 5 players who scored the most goals in their last 5 matches.

This would require matching on each player's last 5 games (via their team nodes and ordering), then matching to the goals in the last 5 games and totaling them up per player.

So to speed things up, you might want to add intermediate nodes to your model that make these traversals easier.

For example, a :PlayerStats node for each player per each team and game that has relationships to goals and assists (up to you if you want to continue to keep the direct relationships from :Goal and :Assist nodes to :Player and :Team nodes). While it complicates the model a bit, and requires more relationships between adjacent nodes, it can speed up traversals for some queries, as it allows easier grouping of stats per player, team, and game, saving you from traversing stats with unrelated dimensions.

I'd also recommend using :ASSISTED and :SCORED for your relationships to the related nodes rather than :STAT_OF, as that can let you query using [degrees of relationships](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-counting-number-of-relationships-on-a-node/) from nodes instead of having to expand to nodes for some queries.

It might also be worth considering removing :Assist nodes and replacing them with just :ASSISTED relationships to the :Goals in question.